# Test mysqli database class with phpunit sqlite memory database

Tags: php, mysqli, phpunit

I have some database classes that are using mysqli.  For example:

```
class MyDB
{
    function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    function add($name)
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (name) VALUES ('$name');"
        $this->db->query($sql);
        if ($this->db->affected_rows) {
            return $this->db->insert_id;
        }

        return 0;
    }
...
```

I would like to test them with phpunit, using an sqlite in-memory database.  However, as expected, I get this error:

> Undefined property: PDO::$affected_rows

According to the documentation:

> PDO is only required for the fixture clean- and set-up and for assertions. You can use whatever database abstraction you want inside your own code.

I suspect that just means that I have to create a wrapper for mysqli that is compatible with PDO.  Or is there a way I can test my code without converting it to use PDO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysqli objects and PDO objects are not compatible. You're passing a PDO object to code that's expecting a mysqli object. If you have mysqli code that you want to test, you have two choices:

1. Use mysqli for the testing. This (as far as I know) rules out an in-memory database.
2. Convert all your code to PDO. This allows you to pass any PDO object, be it MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, whatever. That's kinda the point of using PDO.

I would not write a wrapper. That introduces unnecessary complexity that would itself need to be tested. And if you're going to expend that much effort, you may as well spend it converting to PDO.